# SQL HierarchyID data type , how to generate OrgNode for fast inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m thinking about changing a parent child hierarchy table to hierarchyid datatype,
I am looking for  T-sql querty (I guess it will be implement with  CTE) that will help me to generate new nodes and insert them to the hierarchyid table
I have seven fixed level that I can run one by one and find for each level all of his new nodes.
Now, the problem is that I need it to be inserted without using inline function or cursor, due to large amount of member ( about 1Mil at the low level).
I have a query that return all the new node that need to be inserting with their parents
Mean: I have list of @parentOrgNode hierarchyID ,@NewCustomerCode varchar(255)
For example : list of new node (level 4) that need to be insert

```
select distinct  C1.orgNode as ParentCode,S.PH1_LVL4_NAME,S.PH1_LVL4_CODE
from [Staging].[dbo].[CustomerHierarchy] S
inner join customer C1 on C1.CustomerCode=PH1_LVL3_CODE
left outer join Customer C2 on C2.CustomerCode=PH1_LVL4_CODE
where C2.CustomerCode is null
```

For each return row need to generate OrgNode  for inserting to Customer table
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Say you had the following table

```
create table customer_hierarchy (
    customer_id int not null constraint pk_customer_hierarchy primary key,
    parent_customer_id int references customer_hierarchy
);
```

Here's a couple of ways you could generate a hierarchy out of it. The first uses the existing ids in the hierarchy. The second collapses them to consecutive integers:

```
with cte as (
    select
        '/' + cast(h.customer_id as nvarchar(3998)) + '/' as pos,
        customer_id
    from
        customer_hierarchy h
    where
        h.parent_customer_id is null
    union all
    select
        pos + cast(h.customer_id as nvarchar(3998)) + '/',
        h.customer_id
    from
        cte c
            inner join
        customer_hierarchy h
            on h.parent_customer_id = c.customer_id
) select
    cast(pos as hierarchyid) pos,
    customer_id
from
    cte
```

using row_number()

```
with cte as (
    select
        '/' + cast(
            row_number() over (order by customer_id) as nvarchar(3998)
        ) + '/' as pos,
        customer_id
    from
        customer_hierarchy h
    where
        h.parent_customer_id is null
    union all
    select
        pos + cast(
            row_number() over (
                partition by c.customer_id 
                order by h.customer_id
            ) as nvarchar(3998)
        ) + '/',
        h.customer_id
    from
        cte c
            inner join
        customer_hierarchy h
            on h.parent_customer_id = c.customer_id
    ) select
        cast(pos as hierarchyid),
        customer_id
    from
        cte
```